# File posting using cURL into a secured folder(https://)

Tags: php, page-curl

The problem is to upload a txt file into a secured folder(`https://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/`) using cURL.

I have a relevant ftp details to connect that folder. here is my code, but it does not getting connected properly...

can any one please advise what mistake i did on this code. which returns error_no:7 while uploading file

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if ($_FILES['upload']['name']!="") 
    {
        $localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $newfile = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'ftp://ftp_login:password@ftp.mydomain.com/myfolder/'.$newfile;
        $fp = fopen ($localfile, "r");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPASCII, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $newfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        echo $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //echo $result;

        if ($error_no == 0) 
        {
            $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $error = 'File upload error.';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $error = 'Please select a file.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: FTP and HTTPS are different protocols.  FTP does not natively support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this list](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), error code 7 is

```
CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)

Failed to connect() to host or proxy.
```

Are you sure the server is reachable? Can you try manually?

Also, I'm not really getting what you are doing here. You are establishing a `ftp` connection but adding POST fields. Also, nothing of this has to do with https. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have to use cURL but PHP has its own [FTP functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) that will make life a bit easier.